I would like to use the voice file created using Google Cloud TTS for commercial purposes
hello? I am a Korean SW developer.
Currently, I have implemented a program that creates a voice file using Google Cloud TTS in a Python environment using a free personal license json file.
In the future, we plan to install voice files in our products and use them as guidance voices.
Therefore, I would like to know how to use voice files created using Google Cloud TTS for commercial purposes.
Google's site says up to $300 is free. Can I use the audio file created using the free personal license json file for commercial purposes?
Or are other additional procedures or payment registration required?
